# Accelerometer keeps returning null

Tags: android, accelerometer

I'm attempting to use the Accelerator in Android, but am having trouble with getting any results.

The accelerometer keeps returning null, and I'm not quite sure if the event listener is the problem, or something else.

What I believe is relevant to the problem:

```
public class CalibrateScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener{

    private SensorManager sensorMan;

    private float mAccel;
    private float mAccelCurrent;
    private float mAccelLast;
    boolean Calibration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calibrate_screen);

        sensorMan = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        Sensor accelerometer = sensorMan.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sensorMan.registerListener(CalibrateScreen.this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        mAccel = 0.00f;
        mAccelCurrent = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
        mAccelLast = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
        Calibration = true;

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
            // Shake detection
            float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
            float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
            float z = sensorEvent.values[2];
            mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
            mAccelCurrent = (float) Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
            float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
            mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta;
            //mAccel is the current acceleration.
            if (Calibration) {
                addMember(mAccel);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sensorMan.registerListener(this, sensorMan.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        sensorMan.registerListener(this, sensorMan.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        sensorMan.unregisterListener(this);
        super.onStop();
    }

}
```

The full code pastebin is here: https://pastebin.com/uREm9Esd

Thank you for your time in advance

Comment: Please explain what you mean when you say "The accelerometer keeps returning null".  Do you mean this line returns null: 
 `sensorMan.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);` ?

Comment: The acclerometer data array, sensorEvent, seems to always end in null

Answer (score 0):

```
mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
mAccelCurrent = (float) Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
```

problem is in first line it must go after delta calculation not before;
with such bug you got not null you got 0 values!

FYI: and I hear somewhere sometimes in accelerometer it really can return null, but didn't see such situation jet;